# Custom WP_Query posts_per_page not filtering for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Have this code block

```
<?php

$custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'posttype',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
));

?>
<div class="container" data-category="<?php echo $category; ?>">
    <?php
    // Check if there are any posts
    if ($custom_query->have_posts()) {

        // Start the loop
        while ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
            $custom_query->the_post();
            get_template_part(
                'partials/card',
                null,
                array(
                    'category' => $category
                )
            );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

this file is used in another file with similar code for another custom post type

Wan to filter the posts to 6 post for each custom post type